# How can I stop Firefox throwing a NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED error?

Tags: firefox

I had a powercut last night and ever since then when I try to access the Ask Ubuntu Chat, I see the following error in Firebug.

```
Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [nsIDOMStorage.getItem]
```

I assume I'm getting this because the storage that Firefox uses for HTML5 local storage (which SE Chat uses to cache the session) has been corrupted by the dirty reboot.

No amount of force-refreshing seems to fix this, so what do I do now?

I have already tried:

- Nuking my "Offline Storage" from the Preferences screen.
- `rm`ming localstore.rdf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firefox stores its HTML5 data in a file called `webappsstore.sqlite`. That's sitting in your profile directory which lurks somewhere in `~/.mozilla/firefox/....default/` (depending on what your profile is called).

Move that out the way and restart Firefox and everything will come back to life.

- More: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data)

Comment: This can also happen with pentadactyl, in which case delete the cache.zip file (in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<your profile>.default\dactyl\)

Comment: This fixed Slack and Trello for me.

Comment: This is a potentially destructive action (you will lose local storage data). A possibly better solution is outlined in https://askubuntu.com/a/1181926/556982

Comment: Is there a way to recover data from the corrupted `sqlite` file? opening it in a regular sqlite browser doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3):

What fixed it for me when I had that error with BitBucket (again) was the clicking the button `Clear Cookies and Site Data...`. You can arrive at that button by clicking at the symbols right before the web address (an `i` withing a circle, or a green lock, or a crossed out lock, or something similar). Then you get a popup dialog at the end of which you can find the aforementioned button:
[image: An image of the "Clear Cookies and Site Data..." button.]

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Okay. If I recall correctly, the timing might have been important as well. It might have mattered whether I clicked that button at the login screen, during login process, or after logging in - it displayed a different cookies at different points (parent company vs specific product). To be certain, one might want to delete cookies at each of those points.
---
But it is also completely possible you and I had different problems with different solutions, while seeing the same error message.

Comment: Deleting the sqlites files did not works for me. I needed to additionally clear the site data. Now it seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue using a procedure similar to the one outlined in https://superuser.com/a/1329161 (replace `places.sqlite` with `webappsstore.sqlite` in those instructions). The advantage is that this preserves (uncorrupted) content of `webappsstore.sqlite`, which contains local storage data.